# OR in Expectation

Tags: java, jmock

How can I do an OR operation when specifying my expectations ? The arguments can either be 10 or 11.

```
public void testGetRandom() {
    context.checking(new Expectations() {{
        oneOf (myrandom).isSpecific(10)  **OR** oneOf (myrandom).isSpecific(11);
    }});

    context.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use [argument matches](http://jmock.org/matchers.html) - last one

example (untested):

```
oneOf (myrandom).isSpecific(with(anyOf(10,11)));
```